# Sharepoint 2007 WarmUp Script (Memory Leak Possibly)

Tags: 2007, development, search, spweb, https

I was wondering if there is any way I can get a SPsiteCollection object using a URL + if I can dispose it using "using" keyword as well.

I want to go through all the SPWebAPplications in a Local farm, and then each SiteCollection, its site and All respective subwebs.

I am able to do it but memory resources being used for too much, All I am actually trying to do is create a Sharepoint warmup script in a console App.

```
                   class Program
{
    public static ArrayList siteCollArray = new ArrayList();
    public static ArrayList FailedURLs = new ArrayList();
    public static ArrayList URLs = new ArrayList();
    public static InitValues initVals = new InitValues();
    public static Log log = new Log();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        log.AddeventLog("Started running at " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + "Running on the system " + System.Environment.MachineName

);

    GetSiteCollections();
    GetSubWebs();
    GetWebPage();

    foreach(string url in FailedURLs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(url);
    }

    SendEmail();
}

private static void GetSiteCollections()
{
    try
    {
        SPFarm farm = SPFarm.Local;
        SPWebService service = farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>("");

        foreach (SPWebApplication webApp in service.WebApplications)
        {
            foreach (SPSite currentsite in webApp.Sites)
            {
                SiteCollection newSite = new SiteCollection(currentsite.Url, initVals.verbose);
                siteCollArray.Add(newSite);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.AddeventLog("Error getting SiteCollections off Sharepoint Farm. Exception: " + ex.ToString());
    }
}

private static void GetSubWebs()
{
    try
    {
        foreach (SiteCollection currentSite in siteCollArray)
        {
            ArrayList subWebs = currentSite.subWebs;
            foreach (string URL in subWebs)
            {
                URLs.Add(URL);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.AddeventLog("Error getting SubWebs off Site Collection. Exception: " + ex.ToString());
    }
}

public static void GetWebPage()
{
    foreach (String URL in URLs)
    {
        try
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(URL);
            request.Proxy = null;

            if ((initVals.userName == null) || (initVals.userName == ""))
            {
                request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            }
            else
            {
                CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
                myCache.Add(new Uri(URL), initVals.authType, new NetworkCredential(initVals.userName, initVals.password, initVals.domain));
                request.Credentials = myCache;
            }

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription);
            using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
            {

                string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
                dataStream.Close();
                response.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.AddeventLog("Web Url: " + URL + " &  Exception Message: " + ex.Message.ToString());
            FailedURLs.Add(URL);
        }
    }
}
```

Caution its not complete code but enough to demonstrate what I am trying to do and main problem is memory leak.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of collecting all the SiteCollections and then all the Site I'd run though all in one sweep, collect the Url and deallocate when done with each:

In Main:

```
foreach (SPWebApplication webApp in service.WebApplications) 
{ 
  foreach (SPSite currentsite in webApp.Sites) 
  { 
    ProcessWeb(currentsite.RootWeb);
    currentsite.Dispose();
  } 
}
```

In ProcessWeb:

```
URLs.Add(currentWeb.Url);
try
{
  foreach (SPWeb web in currentWeb.Webs)
  {
     ProcessWeb(web);
  }
}
catch ...
finally
{
  currentWeb.Dispose();
}
```